# longest valid parantheses Line 1061: Char 9: runtime error: addition of unsigned offset to 0x610000000340 overflowed to 0x6100000002c0 (basic_string

Tags: c++, stack

```
class Solution {
public:
    int longestValidParentheses(string s) {
        stack <char> stak;
        int n=s.size();
        int i=0;
        
        while(i!=n)
        {
            if( stak.empty() )
            {
                stak.push(i);
            }
            else if(s[stak.top()] == '(' and s[i] == ')' )
            {
                stak.pop();
            }
            else
            {
                stak.push(i);
            }
            i++;
        }//while loop ends here;
        
        
        
        if(stak.empty())
        {
            return n;
        }
        else
        {
            int maxx=0;
            //n=n-1;
            while(!stak.empty())
            {
                //return stak.top();
                maxx=max(maxx,n-stak.top()-1);
                n=stak.top();
                stak.pop();   
            }
            maxx=max(maxx,n);
            return maxx;
        }
        
    }
};
```

- am getting an runtime error : Line 1061: Char 9: runtime error: addition of unsigned offset to 0x610000000340 overflowed to 0x6100000002c0 (basic_string.h) SUMMARY: UndefinedBehaviorSanitizer: undefined-behavior /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/../../../../include/c++/9/bits/basic_string.h:1070:9*

Comment: The problem is to find valid longest parantheses from a given string , it has passed 118 testcases out of 231

Comment: Thankyou for including the error message, but could you also indicate which line is line 1061? It would save people a lot of trouble trying to answer this.

Comment: Sorry man, I don't have any idea about the same.

Comment: `s[stak.top()]` you are indexing into the string using the top item on the stack as index, thats cant be right

Answer (score -1):

The type of `stack` element should be `int` not `char`. I suppose that this code above is your revision.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).